# Save a form when closing the browser - Angular 5

Tags: c#, angular5

So, i have a doubt. Is possible save a form in a database when closing the browser?

Example, I'm filling out a form and unintentionally closed the page I am, can I send this data to persistence once the page or browser is closed?

If yes, does anyone have any page or example of how to do this?

I use Angular 5 in the front-end in back i use .Net.

Comment: `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` is the key here. I have used this successfully in a past project.

Comment: @DanWilson i will try this and i tell if this resolve my problem. Thanks